# Continue enumeration counters with letters

Tags: numbering, enumitem

I want to continue an enumeration with letters instead of numbers. I use the enumitem package and the resume option.

Example:

> text
>
> a) Some text
>
> b) Some text
>
> Some text
>
> c) Some text
>
> d) Some text

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example. Where do you have trouble? Using letters or resuming the numbering?

Comment: Sorry. Both. But Zarko's answer solved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

exceptionaly, otherwise you should provide minimal working example ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}    % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*]
  \item some text
  \item some text
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[resume*] % <--- changed as suggested Bernard
  \item some text
  \item some text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**edit:** as suggested [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) in his code, by use of `resume*` instead of `resume` the enumerate list overtake settings from the originator list. consequently it is not necessary to repeat `label=\alph*` in it.

[image]

Comment: The `resume*` option would save typing `label=\alph*` again.

Comment: @Bernard, indeed. corrected. thank you very much!